# Problem with two displace (bottom of the sea and continents)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I need mountains on land, but how? I already have one displace (bottom of the sea). Some advice, please?

[image]

Sorry for maybe stupid question. I am beginner and Czech, this is deadly combination.

Comment: Did you render this image or is this a reference? Please also describe the problem in more detail. Do you have both displacement maps but they aren't providing you with the result you want, or are you looking for textures... what is the nature of your problem?

Comment: You can add a second displacement modifier for the land, though I really doubt you need it. Mountains aren't that high compared to the earth. For example, the height of the Mount Everest is less than 0.1% of the diameter of the earth. So if you would have an image of the earth where the earth has a diameter of 1000 pixels, the mount everest would be less than a pixel high.

Comment: I know that, I dont want realism. :-)

Comment: TLousky: Thanks for interest, I already know, what to do. Its about do my own displacement map to get what i want. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right, since displacement can have many levels...(positive and negative, it depend on the "midlevel" you choose), you could displace with an image that could displace both sea depth and land height (mountains): in the image below, with midlevel 0.5, white is above Z=0, black is below Z=0, gray is in the middle (to get Z=0 you need a perfect middle grey, so RGB(0.5,0.5,0.5))

[image]

Can this concept work in your setup?

Since you unaccepted this answer, I guess it doesn't help you really. It's ok.

To the benefit of other readers, too, looking for similar results, I'll add a more "realistic" example with a plane (I know a globe is not as simple, but a plane is simpler to understand), though, to better visualize how it can be done: it is just matter to have at least a very good gradient.

Let's build an "Island"...

I took a height map from http://www.reallusion.com/iclone/Help/EarthSculptor/Image/Utilizing_Height_Map_05.jpg

this:

[image]

and then

- used it as is to create displacement on a plane
- made a colored copy to texture the displacement

[image]

UV map of the texture:
[image]

then you could also paint over the UV texture to "adapt" it to your land/seascape

Comment: Now I get it! :-) Many thanks. It was silly question from me. I must do my own displacement map.

Comment: the only silly question is the question not asked, if you ask me :) about the map, of course your job will be hard, a whole planet with that detail is going to crunch your pc...

Comment: Less detail, understand :-)