# Problem importing grayscale image as planes - Only central portion imported and image not displayed after import

Tags: import

I am complete noob when it comes to Blender.  I am attempting to convert a gray scale image into a 3D relief.  Here's a link to the YouTube video I was attempting to follow.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWFJVvlQIKY  I am importing the gray scale image (.jpg in this case) as planes.  The import appears to sort of work.  In the YouTube video after the import, you can clearly see the contents of the imported image.  For me, all I see is a gray rectangle.

Question 1... Why do I not see the imported image and only see a gray rectangle?

Question 2... Without seeing the image, I thought maybe it was some sort of setting I do not have configured right (I just did a standard install of version 2.78a on Windows 10) and thought I would just continue.  So I did the Edit mode and subdivided the image many times and that at least showed the mesh lines (not sure of the correct terminology) getting smaller and smaller.  Next step I went into the "wrench" mode and did a "Displace" on the image.  This seemed to cause the gray scale image to go into 3D mode but completed exploded.  I reduced the slider down and noticed that only like the middle portion of the image was imported.  Why am I not getting the full gray scale image imported when doing an import as planes?

I hope all that made sense.

p.s.  I have tried this with several different images and image file types and so far all behave the same way.  I cannot see the image after import as planes and it only seems to import the central portion of the image.

Comment: q1: you could need to switch  viewport shading from "solid" to "texture" (at least), q2:  to have the image grey shades to displace the plane, this must be highly subdivided: using a grey shaded image you can obtain a different "heights" for every shaded, subdividing enough (white is high, black is low, greys are in the middle - or the opposite, can't remember now). Eg: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41473/problem-with-two-displace-bottom-of-the-sea-and-continents/

Comment: m.ardito, I am at work at the moment and when I get home tonight I will try the viewport shading change you suggested to see if it will at least display the image.  As for question 2, I do not think that will address the reason blender is only bringing in just the small central portion of the image.  I tried all sorts of things last night trying to get the entire image to be imported but still no luck.  It always (regardless of image) would only bring in only (maybe 1/4 or 1/3) of the image.  The portion it brings in always seems to be only the central portion of the image.